# Using map containing set as a value

Tags: c++, stl

Basically I have,

```
typedef  map<std::string, set<double> > MAP_STRING_TO_SET;
```

What is the best way to update (add or remove value) the set with a new value without causing the set to be copied?

The only viable solution I see is to use `map<std::string, set<double>* >` -- something I don't want to do.

Thanks

Comment: WHy do you think they are being copied?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The set is only copied in initialization.
You are allowed to do something like

```
myMap[myString].insert(myDouble);
```

since map::operator[] returns a reference.

Comment: are you sure?  Wouldn't myMap[myString] create a temporary copy of the set, hence I will NOT actually update the set in the map?

Comment: No, it creates a reference. It is not a temporary copy. Maps would be quite useless otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
map<std::string, set<double> >::iterator iter = myMap.find(myString);
if(iter != myMap.end())
{
 iter->second.insert(myDouble);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can just use swap - eg.

```
my_map["123"].swap(my_set)
```

provided clobbering `my_set` doesn't matter to you. This would swap the previous contents of `my_map["123"]` with `my_set`, and it's fast.

The indexing operator[] returns a reference to the contained `set` - therefore, you can manipulate it just like any other variable. If you want to add/remove individual values, you can just use `insert()` or `erase()` methods - eg. `my_map["123"].insert(123)`.

The copying actually takes place when you assign a new set to the map - eg.

```
my_map["123"]=my_set
```

would create a copy of `my_set`. If you don't need to use the value of `my_set` later, you can use the `swap()` method, which will just shuffle pointers of the two sets. `my_set` will, however, have the contents of the previous `my_map["123"]`.